# String to byte array in java

Tags: java, soap, encoding, base64, gzip

I have a string that is base64 encoded. I have obtained this string by converting a pdf file to GZ format then Base64 as per the requirement. I want to send it to server, but the classes I have generated are using Axis2 and are only accepting byte array for particular soap request.

When I use:

```
base64Str.getBytes()
```

It encodes my string again in UTF-8 (default) and changes the string characters that I was going to send. That's why I am getting this error: file corrupted in server side . When I send my base64 string using SOAP UI tool it works, so I want to convert my base64 string to byte array without changing its characters or some alternative way to do this task.

```
**Base64 String**: H4sIAAAAAAAAAKy4dVScy9Y+iLs7wQmu3TgEd3......

**Above string.getBytes()** => EPR3cn7l/pMgVTTS0sz1XzDAAkIgAQjoHkhY....
```

Comment: Can you please show your code? It is unclear how you receive/send your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [DatatypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html)'s parseBase64Binary, as follows:

```
String encoded = "H4sIAAAAAAAAAKy4dVScy9Y+iLs7wQmu3TgEd3......";
byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

does this help you

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String example = "H4sIAAAAAAAAAKy4dVScy9Y+iLs7wQmu3TgEd3";
        Base64 base64 = new Base64();
        byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(example);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways of dealing with Base64 encoding as was already explained here, but to address directly your question:

```
    String s = "H4sIAAAAAAAAAKy4dVScy9Y+iLs7wQmu3TgEd3";
    System.out.println(s);
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    System.out.println(new String(bytes));
```

If you recreate the String at the destination like this, you do get what you have sent.

Answer (score 0):

Bypass the `String` class entirely. Whatever code you're using to convert to Base64, have it put the data directly into a `byte[]` instead.

If you're on Java 8, use [`java.util.Base64.Encoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html) to do it for you.